# How can I import a file with two different custom extensions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have case where two files with same name but different custom extensions, for example in react native i have :

```
  CompA.android.tsx
  CompA.ios.tsx
```

and i want to import like this **`import CompA from './CompA'`** but i got error from typescript says: **"Cannot find module './CompA' or its corresponding type declarations."**.

I tried to add something in tsconfig, like this

```
"paths": { 
  "*":["src/*","*.android.tsx","*.ios.tsx"],
},
```

but did not work

So is there any configs i can add to make my case works?

Comment: Those are two different files, you are going to have to specify in the code which one you want.

Comment: @JaredSmith the react native metro can decide which one to take based on the current platform, in JS the code is working fine